# Error when creating Cube.js API - Failure at cubestore

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cube.js

I'm working with Cube.js as part of an effort to create a database with front-end visualization. I'm new to the whole system, and am attempting to follow a tutorial posted here:

https://d3-dashboard.cube.dev/setting-up-a-database-and-cube-js

I have the Postgres database established, but when I go to scaffold the project with:

```
npx cubejs-cli create d3-dashboard -d postgres
```

I am receiving an error (below), which seems to be associated with @cubejs-backend\cubestore.

I'm not sure if this is associated with my setup of Node.js. I installed version 14.16.1 and later through some other troubleshooting upgraded npm to version 7.9.0.

Here's the error I'm seeing - any help greatly appreciated:

```
found 0 vulnerabilities
- Writing files from template
- Installing Cube Store driver
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\d3-dashboard\node_modules\@cubejs-backend\cubestore
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./bin/post-install
npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\allenc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-09T16_17_36_455Z-debug.log

Cube.js Error ---------------------------------------

Error: npm install --save-dev @cubejs-backend/cubestore-driver failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\allenc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b15e41626979eec6\node_modules\cubejs-cli\src\utils.ts:14:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\allenc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b15e41626979eec6\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's was an issue, which was already fixed. Can you try with latest releases?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response. I had been using version 14.16.1 of Node.js. Upgraded to version 15.14.0, which seemed to fix the issue.